# FATAL ERROR: v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, javascript-objects, heap-memory, fatal-error

while running the application at first its getting complied successful and its recompiling again and giving a "fatal error"

have tried setting the memory space by the "node --max_old_space_size=8048" but still the process out of memory

ERROR:

√ Compiled successfully.

<--- Last few GCs --->

[9120:043932C8]    79996 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 905.6 (986.8) -> 905.6 (975.6) MB, 831.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.147, current mu = 0.000) external memory pressure GC in old space requested
[9120:043932C8]    80890 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 905.6 (975.6) -> 905.6 (961.1) MB, 893.1 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.074, current mu = 0.000) external memory pressure GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore Allocation failed - process out of memory